# How to Host and Run a Python Script on a Cloud for free and access it online?

Tags: python, sockets, web-hosting, host

I am running a Server hosting my iPhone messaging app. To control this Server, I have coded a python script which controls the Server through the Localhost IP and Port 80. Now, I wish to control the Server remotely, for which I have to create an access mechanism where either by hosting Python script on Cloud, which may be directly connected to the Messaging Server on my Computer, or let both Server and Script reside on my computer while I can access the script remotely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have temporarily hosted a FB app on [pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) for free and it worked like a charm.

In case you plan to use Django, the version they offer usually lags behind.

In that case, I'd higly recommend using [Openshift](https://developers.openshift.com/), by RedHat.

Comment: I came across that, but how to I host the script (and get the IP to send my "iam:---" message?

Comment: Decided on openshift. Have yet to figure out a way to get the ip/port to connect to it.